# Coloring some specific cells on fullcalendar agendaWeek view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to coloring some cells in agendaWeek view according to the start hour of the slot.

For example, slots for 14:00, 14:30 and 15:00 must have red background.

I'm totally lost :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try render it as background Event.

```
event.rendering = "background"
event.color="#ff221e"
```

Comment: Hi.
Is not the cell itself, but this solution works for my purpose.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do basically what you asked. The date part is more just placeholder for you to fill in exactly what you want to be targeted but that will show you where you get that information.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    eventRender:eventRenderCallback,
});


function eventRenderCallback(event, element, view){
    if(view.name==="agendaWeek"){
        if(event.start.format('h:mm') == '14:00'){
            $(element).css('background', 'red');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is for events in that hours. I need coloring the cells without events, the empty slots.